# Google Maps API in Android displays blank screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I've been trying to get Google maps to work in Android Studios.

When creating a new project using the Google maps template, it works fine. However when I implement the map in my existing project, all it displays is a grey screen with the logo in the bottom left.

The existing project uses a fragment navigation system with a single activity that hosts all the other fragments classes. But this shouldn't be the cause of the issue because I implemented the map the same way as in the template, and it didn't work either.

I've checked the Logcat output, and there isn't an error for key validation. If I change the key then the error appears.

Here's the code for the fragment class that contains the map:

```
    public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private MapViewModel dashboardViewModel;

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        dashboardViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MapViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng testLocation = new LatLng(50, -2);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(testLocation));
    }

}
```

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.backintyne">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

The error usually could be caused by any of the following:

- using an API key but from a project without a valid billing account
- using an invalid/incorrect/malformed API key
- using an API key which is restricted to other applications aside from your own
- Maps SDK for Android is not enabled on your project

Make sure you are using an API key from a project that has a valid billing account since it is stated in [Maps SDK for Android documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intro) that before you can start using the Google Maps Platform APIs and SDKs, you must sign up and create a billing account.

If your API key has restrictions, make sure that it is properly restricted according to the [API key best practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey). Make sure that you have enabled Maps SDK for Android for your maps project in the GCP console.

Lastly, if you are still having issues, feel free to [file a support case](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support) to open a personalized communication channel.